# Apply mutate to data frame in R: iterates one extra step and causes error

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I wonder why my get_http_status function iterates once more than necessary causing an exception

I have a data frame like:

```
> str(df5)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ text : chr  "\n" "\n" "\n" "\n" ...
 $ enlace: chr  "//www.blogger.com| __truncated__ ...
 $ Freq  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 r code here
```

I'm trying to get the http status code for each "enlace"
Using this function:

```
get_http_status <- function(url){
  if (!is.null(url)){
    Sys.sleep(3)
    print(url)
    ret <- HEAD(url)
    return(ret$status_code)
  }
  return("")
}


df44 <- mutate(df5, status = get_http_status(enlace))
```

but keeps trowing the error:

```
** Error in parse_url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE**
```

i can warp the function with try/catch and it works, but i don't know why the error is happening in first place.

```
get_http_status_2 <- function(url){
  tryCatch(
    expr = {
      Sys.sleep(3)
      print(url)
      ret <- HEAD(url)
      return(ret$status_code)
    },
    error = function(e){ 
      return("")
    }
  )
}
```

The content of the df5$enlace is:

```
> df5$enlace
 [1] "//www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID=4514563088285989046&widgetType=Attribution&widgetId=Attribution1&action=editWidget&sectionId=footer-3"       
 [2] "//www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID=4514563088285989046&widgetType=BlogArchive&widgetId=BlogArchive1&action=editWidget&sectionId=sidebar-right-1"
 [3] "//www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID=4514563088285989046&widgetType=BlogSearch&widgetId=BlogSearch1&action=editWidget&sectionId=sidebar-right-1"  
 [4] "//www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID=4514563088285989046&widgetType=Followers&widgetId=Followers1&action=editWidget&sectionId=sidebar-right-1"    
 [5] "//www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID=4514563088285989046&widgetType=PageList&widgetId=PageList1&action=editWidget&sectionId=crosscol"             
 [6] "//www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID=4514563088285989046&widgetType=Text&widgetId=Text1&action=editWidget&sectionId=sidebar-right-1"              
 [7] "//www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID=4514563088285989046&widgetType=Text&widgetId=Text2&action=editWidget&sectionId=sidebar-right-1"              
 [8] "http://5d4a.wordpress.com/2010/08/02/smashing-the-stack-in-2010/"                                                                               
 [9] "http://advancedwindowsdebugging.com/ch06.pdf"                                                                                                   
[10] "http://beej.us/guide/
```

I think it iterate one time more because the result of the function is:

```
> df44 <- mutate(df5, status = get_http_status(enlace))
 [1] "//www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID=4514563088285989046&widgetType=Attribution&widgetId=Attribution1&action=editWidget&sectionId=footer-3"       
 [2] "//www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID=4514563088285989046&widgetType=BlogArchive&widgetId=BlogArchive1&action=editWidget&sectionId=sidebar-right-1"
 [3] "//www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID=4514563088285989046&widgetType=BlogSearch&widgetId=BlogSearch1&action=editWidget&sectionId=sidebar-right-1"  
 [4] "//www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID=4514563088285989046&widgetType=Followers&widgetId=Followers1&action=editWidget&sectionId=sidebar-right-1"    
 [5] "//www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID=4514563088285989046&widgetType=PageList&widgetId=PageList1&action=editWidget&sectionId=crosscol"             
 [6] "//www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID=4514563088285989046&widgetType=Text&widgetId=Text1&action=editWidget&sectionId=sidebar-right-1"              
 [7] "//www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID=4514563088285989046&widgetType=Text&widgetId=Text2&action=editWidget&sectionId=sidebar-right-1"              
 [8] "http://5d4a.wordpress.com/2010/08/02/smashing-the-stack-in-2010/"                                                                               
 [9] "http://advancedwindowsdebugging.com/ch06.pdf"                                                                                                   
[10] "http://beej.us/guide/bgc/"                                                                                                                      
 Error in parse_url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

Comment: I don't think `HEAD` is vectorized.

Comment: Your code is printing the entire vector, then trying to pass the entire vector to `HEAD` but `HEAD` only takes 1 url per call.

Comment: Like @SmokeyShakers points out, your error message gives you a good clue: " Error in parse_url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your function contains a function that is not vectored, use the `apply` family of higher order function to iterate over your vector.

Below, `get_http_status` will be called on each element of `df$enlace`.

For each call a length one character vector is expected as the return, `character(1)`:

```
vapply(df5$enlace, get_http_status, character(1))
```

Comment: If possible,  please provide more context or some explanation, in order to add value to your answer.

Comment: This works, he key is your previous comment. "code is printing the entire vector, then trying to pass the entire vector to HEAD but HEAD only takes 1 url per call"

Some reason to use vapply over mutate?

Comment: `mutate` works for vectorized functions. You need to loop because of the function `HEAD` is not vecotrized.. In the 'tidyverse', I believe you'd use something from 'purrr'